# How did Samsung implement the applications screen on the new Galaxy S phone?

Tags: android, mobile

SDK-wise, which UI controls drive it

Comment: You might consider posting some screenshots or otherwise explaining what the heck you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer to you but Samsung has released the code so you can take a look:
http://opensource.samsung.com/

Comment: Looked for it, they don't seem to have any Android releases there

Comment: Type "gt-i9000" (= galaxy S) to search field and download the zip.

Comment: You are very much right, sorry for the hasty down bump. Now all that is left is locating it within the archives (not the easiest of tasks). Thanks

Comment: Please edit the answer so I can remove my initial response (no need to change anything, just add spacing or something)

Comment: No worries. Yeah, it can be very painful to find the code in there :(

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Samsung have implemented it but here is an implementation by Jason Fry

http://jasonfry.co.uk/?id=23